# ListBox.SetSelected after several seconds

Tags: c#, listbox, selection, wait

This is most likely a duplicate question & sorry if it is, but after several Google searches I was unable to find a suitable answer :-(

So I have a ListBox that loads several items & text box's for each as follows:

1. LoadList
2. Load Text Box's (listBox item's values)

I have the above instructions (1 & 2) working great, no problems to report.

My problem starts when using "SetSelected(1,true)" on multiple occasions, because the program simply doesn't have enough time to load the TextBox's values of the selected item.

E.g.

```
listBox1.SetSelected(1, true);  // Text Box's don't load
listBox1.SetSelected(2, true);  // Text Box's don't load
listBox1.SetSelected(3, true);  // Loads Fine, End of selection
```

So my question is  **How to make the program wait for several seconds after making a selection, giving it enough time to load the textBox's ?**

I have looked into timer & System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); , timer just counts & Sleep simply stops the tool completely :-(

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't call `SetSelected` multiple times like that.  You call it once and then let the current method end.  You would then handle an appropriate event to then call it a second time and likewise for the third.  What that event might be is impossible to say because you haven't provided adequate information but that's basically what you need to do.

Comment: I don't get it .. Each listBox item loads text box's when pressed, I want to know how to make it wait for the loading 'method' to end ?

Comment: You don't make it wait.  That's the point.  You just select the first item and then let it go.  Once the loading has finished, then you initiate the selection of the next item.  Instead of just repeating what you've already said, how about you actually edit your question and provide an explanation of what this "loading method" is and does?  That way, we can help you work out how to do something when it's finished.